# Two Place Position and Model Question

Tags: logic, contest-math, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

!

i get trouble in one multiple choice question in logic course: any one could help me with some description ?

if we have Two-place position predicate, like :

[image]

1)  all models of $\varphi$ is infinite.

2) all models of $\varphi$ is finite.

3) $\varphi$ has infinite and finite model.

4)  $\varphi$ has no model .

which of them is correct? any idea?

Comment: All models of $\varphi$ are infinite; check with an interpretation with *domain* the *natural* numbers and with $P$ as $<$ (less-than).

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, i'm not sure. my instructor say (3). any book or prove?

Comment: Your instructor is wrong; @Mauro is right (as usual :-)).

Comment: You can see in Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=4GzCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) (1967 - Dover ed  2002) **Example 4**, page 293.

Comment: DEar @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence $\varphi$ says that $P$ is totally irreflexive and transitive, and that every element is related to some (necessarily other) element. Let $P$ be the relation $<$ on $Z$, the set of integers; it's easy to check that $\varphi$ is satisfied. Thus, $\varphi$ has infinite models.

However, $\varphi$ has no finite model. HINT: Use the first and third conjunct of $\varphi$ to show that in a finite model the second (transitivity) must be violated. You can do this by showing that there must be a cycle:

$$P(x_0,x_1),P(x_1,x_2),\ldots,P(x_{n-1},x_n),P(x_n,x_0)\;.$$

Comment: Well, you only need the third part and finiteness for the existence of a cycle. Then you can notice that a cycle can't simultaneously satisfy first and second part.

Comment: @tomasz: Depends on whether you consider a loop a cycle. I've run into some who don't, so I was playing it safe.